# PHP's MYSQLI get_charset returns wrong charset

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, collation

I do:

`$conn->real_connect($host,$user,$pass,$someUTF8Schema);`

Then I print what I get from:

`$conn->get_charset()`

It is:

charset = "latin1"
collation = "latin1_swedish_ci"

Even though my schema and all tables in the DB are utf8.

To prove it, I do:

```
SELECT DEFAULT_CHARACTER_SET_NAME, DEFAULT_COLLATION_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = $someUTF8Schema;
->
# DEFAULT_CHARACTER_SET_NAME, DEFAULT_COLLATION_NAME
'utf8', 'utf8_unicode_ci'
```

Why is PHP MySQLi returning the wrong collation? Thanks!

Comment: I believe different charset could be defined on the DB table level

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple things that need to coordinated.

1. What encoding are the characters you are manipulating in PHP?
2. Have you told MySQL that encoding via the connection call or `set_charset` or `SET NAMES`?
3. You can fetch that via `get_charset().
4. But the database/table/column do not have to be the same as that --
5. When creating a database, you can establish the *default* charset for *new* tables in that database.
6. When creating a table, you can override that default by explicitly specifying charset for *columns* in that table.
7. When specifying columns, you can override that default by explicitly specifying the charset for that column.
8. When `INSERTing` bytes being inserted are interpreted according to step 2, then converted to the column's charset (#7).
9. Similarly, when `SELECTing`, the characters are re-converted (#7->#2) if necessary.

Note, I did not mention `COLLATION`, only `CHARACTER SET`.  They are *different* animals.  `COLLATION` refer to how to compare characters in a given `CHARACTER SET`.

See the Best Practice section of [Trouble with utf8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) .